# Download Function GridFS and NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, gridfs

I have created a script that uploads the file. The upload part is okay, but the problem is the download. I tried [this link in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33035329/how-to-download-a-file-saved-in-gridfs-using-nodejs) and I think it is not working because I do not get any physical file to be download, but I got a 204 response, meaning the pipe is successful. I want to get a downloadable file. Here is my AJAX Request

```js
_fileUploads.download = function(reload_on_return) {
  var filtered = root.fileUploads().filter(_ => _._id() == _fileUploads._id());
  var index = root.fileUploads.indexOf(filtered = filtered[0]);
  filtered = ko.toJS(filtered);

  swal({
    text: 'Are you sure you want to download the file?',
    buttons: true,
    icon: 'info'
  }).then(function(allowDelete) {
    if (allowDelete) {
      toastrTrigger('The File is being processed')
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/api/gridfs/files/' + filtered._id,
        statusCode: {
          204: function(response) {
            toastrTrigger('The File is being Downloaded')
            window.location = "/api/gridfs/files/" + filtered._id;
          }
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
          toastrTrigger('Bad request', undefined, 'error');
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

And this is the download function:

```js
exports.gridFsFilesDownload = function(req, res) {

  gfs.findOne({
    _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id),
    root: 'uploads'
  }, function(err, file) {

    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send(err);
    } else if (!file) {
      return res.status(404).send(err);
    }

    console.log(file.filename)
    console.log(file.contentType)
    console.log(file._id)

    var readstream = gfs.createReadStream({
      _id: file._id,
      root: 'uploads'
    });

    console.log(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id));
    console.log(req.params.id);

    res.set('Content-Type', file.contentType);
    res.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' + file.filename + '"');

    readstream.on("error", function(err) {
      res.end()
    });


    readstream.pipe(res);
    console.log(readstream.pipe(res));
    console.log('success')

    return res.status(204).send();

  });

};
```